# What software was used to make KDA - Villain?

Tags: 3d

[image: Here's an example]
I want to try making small clips with realistic environment with the lighting in the KDA music video...
Any ideas what kind of program to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video was created by a studio called Trizz; you can see their page about the project [here](https://www.trizz.tv/portfolio/kdavillain). The site doesn’t have any information about what software they used, but you can achieve this look (with enough work) in pretty much any modern renderer. If you use [Blender](https://blender.org), [Cycles](https://www.cycles-renderer.org) is a good one; with other 3D software, [Redshift](https://redshift3d.com), [Octane](https://home.otoy.com/render/octane-render/), and [Arnold](https://arnoldrenderer.com) are popular options.

If you’re also looking to make the kind of physics-based animation—cloth, fire, snakes, etc.—that appears in the video, you’ll probably also want to check out [Houdini](https://www.sidefx.com/products/houdini/).